# UIBarMetrics Value for Custom UINavigationBar with Retina

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, retina-display

I am developing an iPhone app that has a custom nav bar. Here's the code that I have:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIImage *testNav = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Test Nav Bar 320 wide.png"];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:testNav forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

When I Run the application it looks fine. However, I also have a retina version of the nav bar. When I replace:

`@"Test Nav Bar 320 wide.png"`

with the retina graphic:

`@"Test Nav Bar 640 wide.png"`

the nav bar becomes way too big and runs off the screen.

What am I doing wrong? Does it have something to do with the:

`forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault`

I'm fairly new to iOS development and any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple uses a naming [convention](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/SupportingHiResScreensInViews/SupportingHiResScreensInViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH15) for images that allows the system to easily identify images meant for different platforms (such as Retina vs. non-Retina, iPad vs. iPhone) without any effort (except for providing the images) on the user's part.

In your case, just name your image `navbar.png` and the Retina version `navbar@2x.png`. Initiate your image using `[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar.png"]`, and the system will automatically select the right image (even though you never mention `navbar@2x.png` anywhere!).